# Assign listview selected item content to flowdocument name

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

When i add item to listview like this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     ListView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Content = textBox1.Text });            
}
```

and then i try this in listview selection changed event :

```
private void ListView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        FlowDocument dok = new FlowDocument();
        dok.Name = ListView1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        // or like this
        //dok.Name = ListView1.Selectedvalue.ToString();
}
```

i am getting error

> 'System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem: Joe' is not a valid value for
>   property 'Name'

adding items like this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     ListView1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
}
```

solves that problem but than i can not do something like this :

```
{
        foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
        {
            if (item.Content.ToString() == textBox1.Text)
            {
                item.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                item.Background = Brushes.Linen;
                item.FontSize = 16;                   
            }
        }
```

i would like to use first option

```
ListView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Content = textBox1.Text });
```

but I how to assign items content as text to document name? Confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your core problem here is that you are trying to get the text contained in the ListViewItem, but you are calling `ToString()` which gets you nothing but the 'string representation' which in your case is 
`System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem: Joe`

Depending on whether you want the ***name*** or ***value*** associated with the ListViewItem, you would use different methods.

**Method 1**

To get the ***name*** of a `ListViewItem` use the `.Name` property, e.g.:

```
ListViewItem i = new ListViewItem();
i.Name;
```

**Method 2**

If you want to get ***text value*** within the `ListViewItem` use the `.Text` property, e.g.:

```
ListViewItem i = new ListViewItem();
i.Text;
```

Comment: Basically what I'm saying is, your first attempt was perfectly fine except you didn't get the value inside the item :D

Comment: I got the value inside the item,value is string "Joe" but somehow i can't name flowdocument with this string.If i try this it will work FlowDocument dok = new FlowDocument();
                    dok.Name = item.Content.ToString(); but problem is with ListView1.SelectedItem.tostring();,i get the string but it looks like it is not valid..

Comment: @heavy, why not use SelectedItem.Text? or do I misunderstand your problem

Comment: to show i got the string value from selected item i can try this  :         private void ListView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
            FlowDocument dok = new FlowDocument();
            string name =ListView1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            dok.Name = name;            
            } and i am getting same error

Comment: i would love to use 'SelectedItem.Text' but there is no option Text when i type the dot after selecteditem....@user3788486

Comment: @heavy that is really strange, what .NET version are you using?

Comment: @heavy I think the issue might be that you can't get it with the `SelectedItem` but instead you are forced to use `listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;`

Comment: No luck with listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text; Same thing,cant use Text property. .NET 4.5

Comment: What i just discovered is that the string i am getting is not "Joe",it is "System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem: Joe".I will continue investigating after i stop laughing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem :

```
private void ListView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        FlowDocument dok = new FlowDocument();
        foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
            {
                if (item.IsSelected == true)
                dok.Name = item.Content.ToString();
            }
```

Always have to be the hard way.